# Improper Integral: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}{1+e^{-2t}}\ dt$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}{1+e^{-2t}}\ dt$$

I have the antiderivative as

$$-\arctan e^{-t}$$

but when I do it out, I end up getting $$-\frac\pi4 + 0 - \frac\pi2+\frac\pi4$$

However, I understand that the answer should be $$\frac{\pi}2$$

Did I get the antiderivative wrong or something?

Comment: Your antiderivative is correct (please check by differentiating). You probably have a sign error, please check.

Comment: Just a minus sign error, probably due to non-use of parentheses. "At" $\infty$,the $\arctan$ is $0$. At $-\infty$ it is $\pi/2$. So we get $-(0-\pi/2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Just a sign error.
$$\int_0^\infty+\int_{-\infty}^0=0-(-\pi/4)+(-(-\pi/4)-0)=\pi/2.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{1+e^{-2t}}dt&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\left(\left .-\arctan (e^{-t})\right|_{-L}^{L}\right)\\\\
&=-\arctan(0)+\lim_{L\to \infty}\arctan(e^{L})\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\left.-\tan^{-1} e^{-t}\right|^\infty_{-\infty}=(-\tan^{-1}0)-(-\tan^{-1}\infty)=0-(-\frac\pi 2)=\frac\pi 2$$